# Why is jQuery "reloading" itself (via Ajax) after I have included it myself?

Tags: jquery

I'm seeing some strange behaviour on a web page... I have included jQuery (and jQuery UI) using regular script tags. When the page loads I see that the file is loaded (from the local browser cache as there are far-future Expires headers on the file).

However, it seems that jQuery itself initiates a new network request to fetch itself again, including a random parameter value which causes the file to download (ie not use the cached version).

A screenshot from Chrome's network tab:

[image: jQuery loading itself... ?]

This is very strange... what is happening here ?

**UPDATE:** The code that is triggering this behaviour is the following:

```
   $(window).load(function() {
     $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
   });
```

If I change it to this instead, the "double-loading" goes away:

```
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").toggle("fade", 400);
   });
```

So basically, when I'm using the "slide" animation, jQuery and jQuery UI get reloaded with extra network requests, while using the "fade" animation does not.

I want to use the "slide" animation so I need to know what's going on here... !

**UPDATE 2:** Here's a screenshot that shows the call stack when hovering over the "Initiator" script in Chrome:

[image: Detail]

Comment: Don't you use another library dynamically loading them ? Many libraries use jQuery.

Comment: Can you show your page?

Comment: It looks like `$.getScript()` calls.

Comment: Do you have iframes or loaded content ?

Comment: @dystroy: No, there are no iframes or externally loaded content.

Comment: And no other library than jQuery ?

Comment: @dystroy: No other libraries, no.

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi you have something that's attaching a string to the jquery include so that it won't get cached as i understand it...

Comment: @Breezer: Yes, but what I really want to know is (as per the title of my question) why jQuery is reloading itself at all, when I have already included it in the regular way.

Comment: JQuery-Ui might be loading JQuery since its a dependency.

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi could you provide a link to site where we could examine this issue. It is strange so much, I am really interested!

Comment: @zeliboba: It's a business app running on an internal website, so no link is possible. Can't really afford the time to set up / reproduce on a public site. I've switched to the "fade" animation as a workaround.

Comment: [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSPSg/) off your code. I can NOT confirm/reproduce this neither with old jQuery (1.7.2) nor new 2.0.2! No issue for the [fade code](http://jsfiddle.net/fSPSg/1/) either (as expected). You really need to link your site or show more code.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try

```
$(function() {
   $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the content of the callback? I know it sounds obvious but are you sure that the jquery library isn't contained in the html being returned from the ajax callback. That'd be the most likely reason for it to load twice. Check the callback response and see if it's being loaded from there.

Comment: Which callback are you referring to? I am not initiating any Ajax requests on my own, the only thing I'm doing is to call the .toggle("slide") function... which then seems to trigger the Ajax call by itself...

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without the full page code, my guess is that there is code of jQuery  include is inside the toggled container

Answer (score 0):

have u tried using *slideToggle()*, maybe something like:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
     $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").slideToggle();
   });
```

the slideToggle motion effect default is 400 anyway

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation has the following warning for the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method -

> The Ajax module also has a method named .load(). Which one is fired
>   depends on the set of arguments passed.

You could try this instead to rule out any ambiguity

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the contents of #t20ContentRightWrapper with a simple paragraph? If that fixes it you can take out parts of the content to find the offending bit. Also maybe you have two elements with the same id. You could also try redownloading and replacing your jquery.js file. You can still get 1.7.1 from github. But I would try the current version as well and keep it unless it breaks stuff if I were you.

If the problem persists, it would be helpful if you could say what browsers/OSes and versions can we reproduce this on?

Answer (score 0):

The load function means something different than what I think you're expecting:

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the method can be quite simple:

maybe you want to use this instead:

`

```
$(function() {
     $("#t20ContentRightWrapper").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400);
   });
```

`